# How to display GMail labels in Mutt?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, mutt

I'm having a hard time trying to display GMail labels inside Mutt.

I'm able to display the labels folders very easily, but I would like to display the labels for each mail, using index format.

It seems that GMail exposes labels using the extension X-GM-LABELS, but it seems that Mut is not able to get them.

I found a proxy that should do the job: https://github.com/zmughal/gmail-imap-label
but I wasn't able to compile it on my system because of missing dependencies.

Is there a good solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todd Hoffmann created [a patch](https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-dev@mutt.org/msg07593.html) that is able to display labels coming from GMail as if they were X-Label. An up-to-date version can be found [here](https://github.com/sgeb/homebrew-mutt/blob/master/patches/mutt-1.5.23-gmail-labels.sgeb.v1.patch).